# Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QDeclarativeProperty'

Tags: qt, symbian

This code:

```
QGraphicsObject *object=rootObject();
object->setProperty("width", 100);
QDeclarativeProperty(object, "width").write(100);
```

gives the following error:

```
Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QDeclarativeProperty'
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact, complete compiler error output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
#include <QDeclarativeProperty>
```

to the top of your source code. It seems that somewhere in your code, there is already a forward declaration for `QDeclarativeProperty`, so the compiler knows that it is a class/struct, but the actual class definition is missing.

The following source code properly runs through the compiler:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDeclarativeProperty>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QObject *object = 0; // rootObject();
    object->setProperty("width", 100);
    QDeclarativeProperty(object, "width").write(100);   
}
```

When you replace `#include <QDeclarativeProperty>` with

```
class QDeclarativeProperty;
```

you get the following compile time error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:11:38: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QDeclarativeProperty'
main.cpp:4:7: error: forward declaration of 'struct QDeclarativeProperty'
```

Comment: what do you mean by foward declarartion..these terms are new to me

Comment: If you just need a pointer (or a reference) to a class, you can use `class MyClass; ... MyClass* myPtr;`. This is sufficient information for the compiler as long as you do not access members of the class. If you do, you usually get the above error message (`incomplete type`) when you missed to include the proper header file which contains the class definition.

Comment: Can you post the complete, exact compiler error output in your question? It should look similar to the example in my answer